# Gedit LaTeX plugin : pdf creation

Tags: pdf, gedit, latex

I just can't compile a pdf with gedit-latex-plugin. It is working by using pdflatex command in terminal. I try with this .tex file :

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\begin{document}

Hello world

\end{document}
```

The compilation of gedit is resume to save the file. No log file or pdf.

Do you know what I can do ?

Ps: .dvi file works

Comment: Try [Gummi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gummi_(software)) instead. Gedit is not for LaTeX works.